# How do I check and manipulate the data from a flat before loading them to teradata database?

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, teradata

As the topic, how do I manipulate the data from the flat file before loading them onto teradata database using BTEQ script....
I'm unsure which part should the manipulation be written onto the bteq script....

```
                  USING
 ------------------------------------------------------
                 INSERT INTO
 ------------------------------------------------------
                  Values
  In my opinion, data manipulation should be done here
  ------------------------------------------------------

  Table Name : Jerry
    A
  -------
  | 5   |          
  | 6   |          
  | 7   |          
  -------

Values in the data file,
   00005|Jim
   0    |Apple
        |Loop
```

Condition:

The data is read from the data file. The row whose first column is 0 or NULL should not be loaded, also the leading 0 should be executed before loading into the table........

```
Guess:

VALUES 
(
 IF TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :A) != NULL OR IF TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :A) != 0
 THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :A)
,B
,C



 );
```

Comment: BTEQ doesn't provide a way to skip records based on content. TRIM doesn't fail even if no characters are removed, so there is no need for conditional execution there. But if you did need to evaluate something conditionally, SQL uses CASE - WHEN - THEN - ELSE - END syntax.

Comment: So where should I put the CASE-WHEN ? Is it in the VALUES () part ?

Comment: Wherever a scalar expression is allowed, so yes;  that could potentially be in the VALUES clause for an INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't bteq for loading. This was never the intention of this tool.

For conditional Loading, you can put criteria in MLoad in the APPLY Statement. Same to the current tool for loading, TPT. In TPT it's "INSERT INTO  SELECT  from  where ". In addition you can mix Load (Load or Update -Operator) & DML (DDL Operator) in one TPT -script.