# Problem with CASE statement syntax in teradata (BTEQ)

Tags: conditional-statements, case, teradata

I've the following code with regards to inserting and checking values into the teradata database.My point is that data that is read from the flat file whose value after trimming leading 0 is 0 or NULL should not be loaded and if otherwise, the value should be loaded into the target table.......

```
VALUES
(    
  CASE STUD_ID WHEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :STUD_ID) NOT IN ('0', NULL) THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :STUD_ID)
  ELSE NEXT 
  END,
  :B,
  :C

)
```

I've unsure of if the next statement does exist for teradata in the conditioning statement...I've got this error

```
   Illegal expression in WHEN clause of CASE expression.
   Statement# 1, Info =0
```

I tried with the select statement in the VALUES area,

```
VALUES
(
   SELECT (CASE STUD_ID WHEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :STUD_ID) != '0' THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :STUD_ID)
         ELSE 1000
         END )
  FROM :STUD_ID,
  :B,
  :C

)
```

I got this error statement...

```
 Syntax error, expected something like ')' between '(' and 
the 'SELECT' keyword.
```

Answer (score 0):

The `CASE ... WHEN` syntax expects a single value for comparison (i.e. `CASE some_expression WHEN 1 THEN 'Y'`).  Try the `CASE WHEN ...` form instead:

```sql
CASE 
  WHEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :STUD_ID) NOT IN ('0', NULL) 
    THEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :STUD_ID)
  ELSE NEXT 
END
```

You can also do this:

```sql
COALESCE(NULLIF(TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :STUD_ID),0),NEXT) -- Return "NEXT" if 0 or NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues, ravioli fixed the syntax.

But your logic is flawed, too: `TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :STUD_ID) NOT IN ('0', NULL)` will never be true because after trimming zeroes you never get `'0'` and additionally any cpmparison to NULL yields `unknown`. `CASE WHEN TRIM(LEADING '0' FROM :STUD_ID) = '' OR :STUD_ID IS NULL THEN` fixes this.

But based on your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60540302/how-do-i-check-and-manipulate-the-data-from-a-flat-before-loading-them-to-terada) you want to skip this row and this is not possible in BTEQ. Either switch to a load utility/TPT (preferred if it's a larger number of rows) or load the data as is in a staging table and apply the filter when INSERT/SELECTing into the target.